# C# The same item is keep adding to list using Foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, list, foreach

I am trying to go through an xml document and per each node add some attribute values into a list using foreach loop. I am accessing the right part of xml document, but after each iteration of foreach loop, all the values are overwritten with new one. So in the end there is a List of all the same items.

```
IEnumerable<XElements> accesses = steps.Descendants("Access").Where(acc => acc.Attributes("Scope").First().Value == "GlobalVariable);
    foreach (XElement access in accesses)
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement> accessComponent = access.Descendants("Component").ToList();
        newGlobVar.DbName = accessComponent.First().Attribute("Name")?.Value;
        newGlobVar.TagName = accessComponent.ElementAt(1).First().Attribute("Name")?.Value;
      
    globalVariables.Add(newGlobVar);
    }
return globalVariables;
```

Comment: Presumably newGlobVar is something you should recreate in your loop. If its always the same class and you just change properties/fields on it. globalVariables hold references to that class and its always the same reference.  So as you look always at the same instance of the class you see the same values in it. You need to create new instances of the class before adding that to globalVariables.

Comment: You are never creating a new `newGlobVar` but just updating the existing instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one instance of the newGlobVar variable and you change its properties.
That's why also properties of added items do change.
You have to create one new instance of the variable for each foreach loop.